# Draw contours for determined landmark points ( OpenCvForUnity )

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, face-detection

I have worked OpenCV with python before. But I am getting hard to using OpenCV with unity.

**I training data for the specific points on the face. I can find landmark point and I can show that points on the unity webcamTexture but I want to draw contours on landmarks point that is determined by me. Firstly I need to convert landmark points to convex hull points for draw contour among existing points. How can I convert?**

> I tried

```
List<List<Vector2>> landmarkPoints = new List<List<Vector2>>();
OpenCVForUnityUtils.ConvertVector2ListToArray(landmarkPoints) ;
```

> But landmark points doesn't convert. I need to convert landmark points to Hull Points.

```
Imgproc.drawContours (rgbaMat, hullPoints, -1, new Scalar (0, 255, 0), 2);
```

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, finally . If you have match same problem that answer could help you.

```
// detect face landmark points.
OpenCVForUnityUtils.SetImage(faceLandmarkDetector, rgbaMat);
for (int i = 0; i < trackedRects.Count; i++)
{
  List<Vector2> points = faceLandmarkDetector.DetectLandmark(rect);
  List<Vector2> pointss = new List<Vector2>();
  //Draw Contours
  List<Point> pointsss = OpenCVForUnityUtils.ConvertVector2ListToPointList(pointss);
  MatOfPoint hullPointMat = new MatOfPoint();
  hullPointMat.fromList(pointsss);
  List<MatOfPoint> hullPoints = new List<MatOfPoint>();
  hullPoints.Add(hullPointMat);
  Imgproc.drawContours(rgbaMat, hullPoints, -1, new Scalar(150, 100, 5,255), -1);
}
```